# Difference between left R left S category equivalence and left R right S category equivalence?

Tags: ct.category-theory

Is property differ for left(right) R left(right) S category of modules and for left R right S category of modules? What impact on Morita equivalence...

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what you mean? If you spell out what the 'left R left S category of modules' is, then people will have a better chance at being able to answer this question.

Comment: In particular, do you know that a left $R$-module is a right $R^{op}$-module?